# how to get values of rows containing multiple options , on submit in php?

Tags: php, forms, submit, html-select

I have to prepare a shopping cart with products in multiple rows , each row should have option buttons like "product brand" "product weight"... and user should select the product by clicking its checkbox. There is only one button below the table (add to cart) user should select the product by selecting its checkbox and after selecting many products , add them to cart by clicking the add to cart button.

What I have tried:

I created the rows with options and gave each elements in same row, an array as "name" but it didn't work out .

See the following sample code for understanding my work.

```html
<form method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="car">car</option>
          <option value="bike">bike</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>
            <option value="blue">blue</option>
            <option value="red">red</option>
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="cycle">cycle</option>
          <option value="skate">skate</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>
            <option value="male">male</option>
            <option value="female">female</option>
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="dog">dog</option>
          <option value="cat">cat</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>
            <option value="bat">bat</option>
            <option value="ball">ball</option>
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

[image: image link]

Comment: user form input name as array to get multiple value.like  name="checked[]"

Comment: Your questions is not clear, what means 'it didn't work'? There is no errors in this piece of code you show ?

Comment: Please show your current and expected result. BTW In some `select`s you have some incorrect `option` element as parent to other `option` tags

Comment: Please show code that _actually_ reflects what you are doing. The select fields  in what you’ve shown don’t have any name at all, and the checkboxes have `name=""` – that does not match what you said you were doing. And where is the part where you attempted to _process_ the data, after it was submitted?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set an `action` on your form element, containing where the form data should be POSTed to. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Secondly, you need to add `name` attributes to your form elements, so they can later be picked up by your backend script. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Finally, in your backend (presumably PHP), you can pick these values up using `$_POST` (or whatever abstraction is provided for you e.g. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data)

As a final note, please make sure you validate all data coming into your backend!

Answer (score 0):

Add the name attr of required filed as array.

Form will be like.

```
<form method="post">

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="attribute[1]['checked']">
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="attribute[1]['product']">
            <option value="car">car</option>
            <option value="bike">bike</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="attribute[1]['product_prop']">
            <option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="red">red</option>
            </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="attribute[2]['checked']">
    </td>
    <td>
         <select name="attribute[2]['product']">
            <option value="cycle">cycle</option>
            <option value="skate">skate</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
         <select name="attribute[2]['product_prop']">
            <option>
                <option value="male">male</option>
                <option value="female">female</option>
            </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="attribute[3]['checked']">
    </td>
    <td>
       <select name="attribute[3]['product']">
            <option value="dog">dog</option>
            <option value="cat">cat</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="attribute[3]['product_prop']">
            <option>
                <option value="bat">bat</option>
                <option value="ball">ball</option>
            </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

After submit the form you will get the checked row value in array. using loop get the value.

like.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $attr = $_POST['attribute'];

    /*echo "<pre>";
    print_r($attr);*/

    foreach($attr as $key=>$value){

        //get the value of checked row - product, product_prop etc
        if(isset($value["'checked'"]) && $value["'checked'"] != ''){
            echo $product = $value["'product'"];
            echo $product_prop = $value["'product_prop'"];

            //Add your code here
        }
    }
}

?>
```